# Difference between $bundle and bundle()

Tags: entities, debugging

Background information: I'm trying to manipulate the available options of a list type text field, depending on the host bundle:

```
function wtbase_options_list_alter(array &$options, array $context) {
  $fieldDefinition = $context['fieldDefinition'];
  if ($fieldDefinition->getName() == 'field_aos_cell' && $fieldDefinition->bundle() != 'link') {
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
      if ($key == 'link-horizontally-opposing') {
        unset($options[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$fieldDefinition->bundle` part is really confusing. There seems to be a variable  `$fieldDefinition->bundle` (containing the expected bundle name `link`) and a function `$fieldDefinition->bundle()` (containing `field_config`). But I can't access the variable `bundle`, because this crashed with `Cannot access protected property Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::$bundle`.

After some digging I found [FieldConfigBase::getTargetBundle()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/function/FieldConfigBase%3A%3AgetTargetBundle/8.2.x), which did return the expected result and did not crash (yet).

So this leads to two questions:

What is the difference between `$bundle`, `bundle()` and `getTargetBundle()` and which one I'm supposed to use? I'd prefer using variables, because they are visible in Xdebug, while functions are not.

And in a more general point of view, are there some guidelines when to use functions and when to use variables? In the same example as above Xdebug printed the same weird results for e.g. `entity_type` vs `entityTypeId` vs `getEntityType()` vs `getEntityTypeId()`.

--

Update, clarification for question 1:

I know the technical difference between a member property and a member function. But I'm deeply confused that a property `$bundle` and a function `bundle()` of the exact same name are returning values from a completely different entities/context. In my example `$fieldDefinition->bundle` returns a Paragraph bundle name `link`, while `$fieldDefinition->bundle()` seems to return the bundle name from FieldConfig. I know this is technically possible... but why would anyone write code like this? I've not yet experienced this behavior anywhere else in Drupal core, usually `$entity->bundle` and `$entity->bundle()` return the same result.

Answer (score 3):

`bundle` is the property on the object. It's where the value is stored. Properties can be assigned one of three ways:

- `public`: these properties can be directly set or read on the object. Example:

  ```
  $object->key = 'value';
  $value = $object->key;
  ```
- `private`: These can only be accessed by methods (functions) of the class itself. Nothing else can access it. For example, this will throw an error:

  ```
  $value = $object->key;
  ```

  Whereas this would be allowed:

  ```
  class Example {
    private $key;

    function getPrivateValue() {
      return $this->key;
    }
  }

  $value = $object->getPrivateValue();
  ```

  `$key` cannot be accessed outside of the class, since it is private. This can be used to enforce rules on the types of data to be stored in the property. Checks can be run to ensure it's an allowed data type.
- `protected`: These are like private properties, however if a class extends the class, the extended class can access the property. If the property is private, extended classes cannot access it.

One thing for you to understand is that `$node->bundle` and `$node->bundle()` are not the same things. The first is a property, the other is a method. This should help understand, as a (non-real) example:

```
class Node {
  protected $bundle;

  public function bundle() {
    return $this->bundle;
  }
}
```

The above class has the property `$bundle`, and the method (function) `bundle()`. The method returns the value stored in the property.

Look at the error you are seeing: `Cannot access protected property Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::$bundle`. This is because you are trying to access the `$bundle` property, but it is protected, meaning you cannot access it from outside the class.

To get the bundle of a node, you need to call the `bundle()` method on it, which will give you the bundle type. This is the answer to your question about which to use.

> And in a more general point of view, are there some guidelines when to  use functions and when to use variables?

It's generally thought to be a best practice to not provide direct access to properties on objects, and instead create setter and getter methods (functions) on objects to set and retrieve the property values. That way you can say, enforce a pattern:

```
class Example {

  protected $username

  public function setUsername($username) {
    if (!is_string($username)) {
      throw new \Exception('Username must be a string');
    }
    elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}$/', $username)) {
      throw new \Exception('Username must be between 3 and 12 characters, and may contain only alphanumerics, underscores or hyphens');
    }

    $this->username = $username;
  }

  public function getUsername() {
    return $this->username;
  }
}
```

The above enforces that username is both a string, and is the right length and only contains allowed characters.

Edit: Additional comment from Leigh:

another reason to avoid accessing the property directly is when you have multiple values. e.g. if you have a field "my_field" on a node which has multiple values if you use $node->my_field->value you'll only get 1 value returned

Comment: Also just to add to this, another reason to avoid accessing the property directly is when you have multiple values. e.g. if you have a field "my_field" on a node which has multiple values if you use $node->my_field->value you'll only get 1 value returned

Comment: Good point. I'll add it to my post.

Comment: I got the basic, technical difference between a member property and a member function... but why would anyone write code that returns _semantically_ different things for those two? In my example above `link` is from Paragraphs, while `field_config` is from FieldConfig.

Comment: `bundle()` will return a string containing the bundle name. Your original post doesn't really make sense in that regard. If it is returning anything other than a string containing the bundle name, you've either misdiagnosed the issue, or you've got a broken system, and some module/theme is doing wonky stuff breaking core functionality.

Comment: I believe they're provided by different classes, getTargetBundle() from the Field class and bundle() from the Entity class. You see both because the fields/configs are effectively entities. Which I'd say is why you see  overlapping functions/data

Comment: As a side note, want to mention that this is why a language aware IDE like PhpStorm is almost essential to avoid frustrations like this.  Autocompleting and being able to see docblocks on the interfaces is a huge help.

Comment: @mpdonadio I'm using PhpStorm with XDebug, but I can't see any member functions or interface methods while drilling down objects in the debug window, only properties/variables. And most hooks are stuffed with array parameters instead of objects, which means there is no autocomplete either (unless I'm manually researching and adding `/** @var ...*/` hints, which kind of defeats the purpose of an _auto_complete).

Comment: I'm unclear. I feel I've answered the question you asked in the original post, but your comments seem to indicate that the issue is still unresolved. As such, I think your post needs improvement, since it's not clear what feel is left unanswered from the original post.